# Questions on Theorem 5.5.7. in Brown-Ozawa

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I am currently trying to digest the proof of Theorem $5.5.7.$ in the book "$C^*$-algebras and Finite-Dimensional Approxmiations" by N. Brown and N. Ozawa.

Background:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space (of bounded geometry/uniformly locally bounded) and denote by $B(x,S)\subseteq X$ the open ball centered at $x$ of radius $S$. Also, we denote by $\ell_n^2$ the $n$-dimensional Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{\eta_i\}$ and by $A(X),C_u^*(X)$ the translation algebra respectively the $\textit{uniform Roe algebra}$ associated to $X$ (i.e. the closure of $A(X)$ in $B(\ell^2(X))$). Finally, $(e_{ij})$ will denote the standard matrix units (in $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$).

I have the following three questions (and I would be very happy to receive even partial answers/ideas to any one of them):

$(1)$: How does one realize that $\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{M}_k(\mathbb{C})\cong \ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})\otimes \mathbb{M}_k(\mathbb{C})$? I suppose that the implication "$\supseteq$" is clear enough.

$(2)$: Assume that there exists $S>0$ such that for every $x\in X$ there is an element $\zeta_x\in \ell^2(X)$ with $||\zeta_x||=1$ and $\text{supp}\zeta_x\subseteq B(x,S)$. Now, the operator $V_x\colon \ell^2(X)\to \ell^2(B(x,S))$  given by $\delta_y\mapsto \zeta_y(x)\delta_y$ satisfies that $\sum_{x\in X}V_x^*V_x=1$ strongly ($\textbf{why?}$) and so defines a u.c.p. map ($\textbf{why?}$) $\psi\colon \prod_{x\in X}B(\ell^2(B(x,S))\to B(\ell^2(X))$ given by $$\psi((b_x)_{x\in X})=\sum_{x\in X}V_x^*b_xV_x$$
(here, complete positivity is true for every $x$-coordinate, but I fail to see how this gives me what I want).

$(3)$: Given $\mathcal{H}=\ell^2_n\otimes \ell^2_n$, we turn $\mathcal{H}\otimes C_u^*(X)$ into a Hilbert $C_u^*(X)$-module through the inner product given by $\langle \xi_1\otimes a_1, \xi_2\otimes a_2\rangle = \langle \xi_1,\xi_2\rangle_\mathcal{H} \cdot a_1^*a_2$. Now, let $\psi\colon \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{C})\to C_u^*(X)$ be completely positive and let $[b_{ij}]=[\psi(e_{ij})]^{1/2}\in \mathbb{M}_n(C_u^*(X))$. From this, we define the element
$$\xi_\psi=\sum_{j,k}\eta_j\otimes \eta_k\otimes b_{kj}\in \mathcal{H}\otimes C_u^*(X)$$
It is claimed that "Perturbing $\xi_\psi$, we may assume that $\xi_\psi\in \mathcal{H}\otimes A(X)$". I do not see which kind of "perturbation" that is needed to achieve this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: In their proof, its not $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} M_n$, its $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} M_k$ - i.e., the size of the matrix algebras is stationary. With this, $\prod_n M_k$ is just bounded sequences of elements of $M_k$. From here, it's not too hard to construct an isomorphism $\prod_n M_k \simeq \ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N}) \otimes M_k$.

Comment: @PStheman Thank you for noticing this! My insecurities stand, however. On the algebraic tensor product alone, the right-hand side allows for only finitely many specifications of $M_k$ (whereas the left-hand side can have arbitrarily many). Thus, I suppose that one should argue that all elements in the product set can be written as a norm-limit of finite specifcations. Would you say that finite dimension of $M_k$ plays a crucial role here?

Comment: @Deracless Have you been able to calculate explicitly $V_x^*$?

Comment: @QuantumSpace My guess would be that $V_x^*$ is given by $\delta_y\mapsto \overline{\zeta_y(x)}\delta_y$. My issues may lie entirely in the understanding of strong convergence. Like; if $\sum_x V_x^*V_x\delta_y=\delta_y$, can we then conclude $\sum_x V_x^*V_x=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For C$^*$-algebras, the norm in the direct product is the supremum norm. This is natural if one thinks of the direct product as forming a "block diagonal". Thus
   $$
   \prod_n A=\{f:\mathbb N\to A,\ \text{ uniformly bounded}\}=\ell^\infty(\mathbb  N,A). 
   $$
   So one needs to check that $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N,A)\simeq \ell^\infty(\mathbb N)\otimes A$  when $\dim A<\infty$. If we fix a basis $a_1,\ldots,a_r$ of $A$ any $f:\mathbb N\to A$ is of the form $f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^r x_{n,k}\,a_k$, where $x_k=(x_{n,k})_n\in\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$. Then we define the map
   $$
   \gamma:f\longmapsto \sum_{k=1}^r x_k\otimes a_k.
   $$
   Using that $a_1,\ldots,a_r$ form a basis, it is easy to see that $\gamma$ is bijective. Linearity and multiplicativity are also trivial, as is the fact that $\gamma$ preserves adjoints.
2. In the canonical basis the operator $V_x$ is "diagonal", since its sends $\delta_y$ to a multiple. It follows that
   $$
   V_x^*\delta_y=\overline{\zeta_y(x)}\,\delta_y,\qquad\qquad\text{ and } \qquad\qquad V_x^*V_x\,\delta_y=|\zeta_y(x)|^2\,\delta_y. 
   $$
   Then, for any $F\subset X$ finite,
   $$
   \sum_{x\in F}V_x^*V_x\sum_y\alpha_y\delta_y=\sum_{x\in F}\sum_y\alpha_y|\zeta_y(x)|^2\,\delta_y=\sum_y\alpha_y\Big(\sum_{x\in F}|\zeta_y(x)|^2\Big)\,\delta_y\xrightarrow[F]{}\sum_y\alpha_y\delta_y
   $$
   since $\sum_{x}|\zeta_y(x)|^2=1$. That is, $\sum_xV_x^*V_x\to1$ sot.

When you apply $\psi^{(n)}$ to a positive $n\times n$ matrix $[(b^{(k,j)}_x)_x]$ (where positivivity means positivity for each $x$) you get
$$
\sum_x[V_x^*b^{(k,j)}_x V_x]_{k,j}=\sum_x\begin{bmatrix} V_x\\ &\ddots\\&&V_x\end{bmatrix}\big[b_x^{(k,j)}\big]\,\begin{bmatrix} V_x\\ &\ddots\\&&V_x\end{bmatrix}^*\geq0
$$

3. Given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists elements $b_{kj}'\in A(X)$ such that $\|b_{kj}-b_{kj}\|<\varepsilon/n^2$. Then
   $$
   \xi_\psi'=\sum_{j,k}\eta_j\otimes \eta_k\otimes b_{kj}'\in \mathcal{H}\otimes A(X)$$ and $\|\xi_\psi'-\xi_\psi\|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. All of it seems to work out nicely. However, further on in the proof (and something that I forgot to mention), it seems necessary to have that $\langle \xi_\psi,\xi_\psi\rangle=\psi(1)=1$ in order to conclude that the collection $\{\zeta_x\}_{x\in X}$ consists of unit vectors. This is easily verified for the initial specification of $\xi_\psi$, but establish the same property for an element $\xi'_\psi\in \mathcal{H}\otimes A(X)$?  Thank you again!

Comment: The proof ends with an estimate, so as far as I can tell you can do a further approximation.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer $(1)$. More generally, if $M$ is a von Neumann algebra, and $I$ is an index set, then
$$\prod_{i \in I} M \cong \ell^\infty(I)\overline{\otimes} M$$
where the tensor product is the von Neumann tensor product. In your case, $M$ is finite-dimensional, so the von Neumann tensor product is just the algebraic tensor product which leads to
$$\prod_{i \in I} M_k(\mathbb{C}) \cong \ell^\infty(I)\odot M_k(\mathbb{C}).$$

In an ad hoc way, we can proceed in multiple ways. For example, we have a canonical chain of $*$-isomorphisms
$$\prod_{i \in I} M_k(\mathbb{C})= \ell^\infty(I, M_k(\mathbb{C})) \cong M_k(\ell^\infty(I)) \cong  \ell^\infty(I) \odot M_k(\mathbb{C}).$$

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a reference in mind for this result?

Comment: Uhm not really: but the proof is easy enough: if $M\subseteq B(H)$ embed $\prod_{i \in I} M\subseteq B\left(\bigoplus_{i \in I} H\right)$. On the other hand, $\ell^\infty(I)\overline{\otimes} M$ embeds in $B(\ell^2(I)\otimes H)$. Now we observe that there is a unitary $\ell^2(I)\otimes H\cong \bigoplus_{i \in I} H_i$ and this unitary implements the desired $*$-isomorphism.